# Is it possible to implement both List<SuperClass> and List<SubClass>?

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, covariance

Let's take the following code as an example:

```kotlin
val immutableList: List<Any> = listOf<String>()
val mutableList: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf<String>()

interface SuperList : List<Any>
interface SubList : SuperList, List<String>
```

As expected, assigning `immutableList` is allowed, which from my understanding of [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) is because it's marked to say it will only ever return values of `T` and never take them, so it doesn't matter if it's `Any` or a subclass.

Also as expected, assigning `mutableList` gives an error because it cannot offer that guarantee, as casting to `MutableList<Any>` would let you add an `Any` to a list of `String`s and that would be bad.

I would expect the interface `SubList` to be fine for the same reason that `immutableList` is: `List`'s generic functions will only give `T`, never take it, so returning a `String` would make both happy. However, its declaration throws the same error as `mutableList`:

```
Type parameter E of 'List' has inconsistent values: String, Any
Type parameter E of 'Collection' has inconsistent values: String, Any
Type parameter T of 'Iterable' has inconsistent values: String, Any
```

Why is this?

---

Things I've attempted, when trying to understand the cause:

- Having `SubList` inherit from `List<Any>` directly rather than `SuperList`: Gives the same error, so this isn't due to something funky with the layers in the inheritance.
- Having `SuperList` inherit from `List<out Any>` rather than `List<Any>`: Gives the error `Projections are not allowed for immediate arguments of a supertype`.
- Having `SuperList` take a type parameter. This works but like... at that point why does `SuperList` even exist, lol. Much better for my use case to just take an entirely different approach to the goal than to do that.

---

Context:

My goal was a pair of `Table` and `MutableTable` types, and my initial idea was implementing this via extending `List<List>` and `List<MutableList>`, respectively. But I wanted to boil the question down to its simplest form, and so chose non-generic classes to use for the sample code.

I have other ideas on how to implement the types, so I'm not looking for an answer to that. I'd just like to understand the root issue that stops this particular approach from working, so that in the future I don't run into other pitfalls with it in ways that might be harder to dodge.

Comment: What behavior would you expect of `AltList` if you were able to implement both `List<Any>` and `List<String>`? What would the functions return? `Any` or `String`? If `Any`, then it's enough to implement `List<Any>`, if `String`, then why do you need to implement `List<Any>`?

Comment: @gpunto `AltList` was only there to make sure it wasn't in some way due to inheriting from `SuperList` rather than `List<SuperType>` directly, rather than something I was actively looking to use. I've edited the question to try to add more context and clarification.

Comment: This is probably a limitation of the type system, that a type cannot be two versions of the same type at once. It cannot simultaneously be a `List<Any>` and a `List<String>`. With your variable, the compiler isn't treating it as two types at once. It is upcasting one type to another. In each of the two separate scopes on either side of the assignment operator,  the compiler isn't thinking of it as two different types at once.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That makes sense. Unfortunate but not unexpected.